# How can delete "/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" page? (Cloudflare)

Tags: cloudflare

'mydomain.com/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection'

Can I somehow delete page “/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection” from my site? I have disabled Email Address Obfuscation setting, but this page is still available.

Answer (score 3):

1. Log in to cloudflare dashboard.
2. Click your website.
3. Click Scrape Shield from main menu.
4. In 'Email Address Obfuscation', click from On to Off.

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work, it seems this page cannot be deleted? https://community.cloudflare.com/t/page-cdn-cgi-l-email-protection/147159